# Disable/enable XAML animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I have next triggers in my XAML:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsOpened}" Value="true">
        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="-310"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="OpenHelpText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="CloseHelpText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ClosePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="OpenPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="Control"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)">
                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="CloseHelpText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="OpenHelpText" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ClosePanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Hidden}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="OpenPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.30" 
                                                Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

And I have some dynamic parameter that tells whether the animation be enabled, or not.
(Dynamic - means that animation should be enabled/disabled whenever parameter value changes)

What is the best way to disable/enable animation?

**UPD**: As an alternative - is that possible to create the same animation in code?

Comment: Try visualstatemanager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update the trigger criteria on your DataTrigger.**

You are embedding the animations in your DataTriggers already.

In your case, perhaps you can leverage [MultiDataTriggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.multidatatrigger.conditions(v=vs.110).aspx) to account for multiple conditions that must be met.

Answer (score 2):

[Refer this link like dis....](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj709930.aspx)

Bind Element name to main property.Here i used Toggleswitch element name i bind with button

```
 Visibility="{Binding IsOn,ElementName=togglebutton}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Comment: I don't need a button. The parameter I have already in my model. And the main part of my question is about exactly animation - what can I do to turn it off/on?